# Can't compile GTK app for existence space in path MSYS MINGW64

Tags: mingw, gtk3, mingw-w64, msys2, pkg-config

I installed **msys2** and **mingw64** and **mingw64-GTK3** in D:\Program Files\msys which has space in it's path.

After installing mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3 ,mingw-w64-x86_64-make, mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc packages for gtk programming I wanted to compile **main.c** but
it throw this error:

```sh
$ g++ main.c -o myapp_output `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
g++.exe: error: Files/msys/mingw64/include/gtk-3.0: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Files/msys/mingw64/include/cairo: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Files/msys/mingw64/include: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Files/msys/mingw64/include/pango-1.0: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Files/msys/mingw64/include/atk-1.0: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Files/msys/mingw64/include/cairo: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Files/msys/mingw64/include/pixman-1: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Files/msys/mingw64/include: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Files/msys/mingw64/include/freetype2: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Files/msys/mingw64/include/libpng16: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Files/msys/mingw64/include/harfbuzz: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Files/msys/mingw64/include/glib-2.0: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Files/msys/mingw64/lib/glib-2.0/include: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Files/msys/mingw64/include: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Files/msys/mingw64/include/freetype2: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Files/msys/mingw64/include: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Files/msys/mingw64/include/harfbuzz: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Files/msys/mingw64/include/libpng16: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Files/msys/mingw64/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Files/msys/mingw64/include/libpng16: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Files/msys/mingw64/include/glib-2.0: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Files/msys/mingw64/lib/glib-2.0/include: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Files/msys/mingw64/include: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Files/msys/mingw64/lib: No such file or directory
```

my main.c code:

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
void
hello (void)
{
    g_print ("Hello World\n");
}

void
destroy (void)
{
  gtk_main_quit ();
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *button;
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_signal_connect (GTK_OBJECT (window), "destroy",
                        GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC (destroy), NULL);
    gtk_container_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 10);
    button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Hello World");
    gtk_signal_connect (GTK_OBJECT (button), "clicked",
                        GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC (hello), NULL);
    gtk_signal_connect_object (GTK_OBJECT (button), "clicked",
                               GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC (gtk_widget_destroy),
                               GTK_OBJECT (window));
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), button);
    gtk_widget_show (button);
    gtk_widget_show (window);
    gtk_main ();
    return 0;
}
```

I know the reason of the error is the space in "**Program Files**" but How I can solve this problem without cutting all msys folder to another place?

Answer (score 0):

You should not install MSYS2 in a directory that has spaces.  Most people install it to C:/msys64.